# delete old dir, make new empty dir

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, mkdir

The single bash command `>| foo` creates an empty file `foo`, no matter if it was previously nonempty, or empty, or missing.  (It fails if it was read-only, or a directory.)

Is there a similar single command to create an empty directory?  It should work if the dir was there before *or not*, empty *or not*.  Roughly the same as `rm -rf fooDir; mkdir -p fooDir` but without violating Don't Repeat Yourself.  (It's acceptable to fail if dirs or files are read-only.)

The context is a script that makes a dir to store its output, but erases the outputs of any previous run.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the answer is: no. There is no single command for what you are asking for, *at least* according to these two links:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/517329/overwrite-an-existing-directory
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23698183/how-to-force-cp-to-overwrite-directory-instead-of-creating-another-one-inside

All I can say is just use the two separate commands. It may be ugly and "inconvenient", but it is 99% likely the only way to do it.

Comment: Thanks for the links.  One of them gave me the idea to use rsync.

Answer (score 0):

First, find an empty directory.  There's no [universal](https://serverfault.com/questions/819226/is-there-a-directory-equivalent-of-dev-null-in-linux) way to do that, but you can either make one, or find a likely candidate with `find /var -type d -empty | xargs ls -ltd`.  For example, on Ubuntu 14, `/var/lib/ntpdate` has been empty for years.  Another safe bet is `/etc/ppp/resolv`.

Then the single command is `rsync -a --delete /var/lib/ntpdate/ fooDir`.  The trailing slash matters.  Unfortunately, without a universal `/dev/nullDir`, this solution is likely to baffle the newcomer.  So if your script has to do this many times, it's worth it to first create `/tmp/emptyDir` and then use that with rsync.